# MYSQL command gives error while being executed from java. Same command works fine on Linux Terminal. What can be the reason?

Tags: java, mysql, database, linux, terminal

I want to get the **foreign key** and **primary key** information from **information_schema** in **XML** format. For that I am using below command on **linux terminal**.

```
mysql --user=root --password=nikunj@cloud --xml -e  "select CONSTRAINT_NAME,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.key_column_usage where table_schema='bakerydb';"
```

This gives result in XML format. Check the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<resultset statement="select CONSTRAINT_NAME,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.key_column_usage where table_schema='bakerydb'" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <field name="CONSTRAINT_NAME">PRIMARY</field>
    <field name="TABLE_NAME">baked_goods</field>
    <field name="COLUMN_NAME">id</field>
    <field name="REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME" xsi:nil="true" />
    <field name="REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME" xsi:nil="true" />
  </row>
...
</resultset>
```

But while I run the same command on **linux** **terminal** using **Java** file It gives error. Check Out **Java** file below.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class foreignKeydetailXML {

     static final String USER = "root";
     static final String PASS = "nikunj@cloud";
     static final String DATABASE = "bakerydb";


    //cli command= mysql -u root -pnikunj@cloud --xml -e 
    //"select CONSTRAINT_NAME,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.key_column_usage where table_schema='bakerydb';"

    static String queryLine ="select CONSTRAINT_NAME,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.key_column_usage where table_schema=\'" + DATABASE + "\';";

    public static String executeScript (String dbname, String dbuser,String dbpassword, boolean verbose) {
            String output = null;
            try {
            String[] cmd = new String[]{"mysql",dbname,"--user=" + dbuser,"--password=" + dbpassword,"--xml -e","\"" + queryLine + "\"" };
            System.err.println(cmd[0] + " " + cmd[1] + " " + cmd[2] + " " + cmd[3] + " " + cmd[4] + " " + cmd[5]);
            System.out.println(cmd);
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            if (verbose) { 
            InputStream inputstream = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

            // read the output
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            }

            // check for failure
            try {
            if (proc.waitFor() != 0) {
            System.err.println("exit value = " +
            proc.exitValue());
            }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output;
            }

    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        //executeScript (String dbname, String dbuser,String dbpassword, String scriptpath, boolean verbose) 
        executeScript("information_schema", USER,PASS,true);
    }
}
```

What can be the reason? It returns exit value 2.
Previously with bit change in code, It was giving list of **MYSQL** options.

Comment: I hope you don't use that password anywhere else...

Comment: That's my local machine password man. Don't worry. @lc.

Comment: If you run that on a terminal you can have a completely different path to when you execute it in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice three differences between the terminal version and the Java version:

1. The Java version adds an additional argument of `dbname`,
2. `--xml -e` is passed as a single argument in the Java version but as two arguments in the terminal version
3. You have quotes around the query in the Java version

Try (I assume the `dbname` is correct here so I am leaving it):

```
String[] cmd = new String[] {
    "mysql", 
    dbname,
    "--user=" + dbuser,
    "--password=" + dbpassword,
    "--xml",
    "-e",
    queryLine};
```

Also, it could be simply that it cannot find the command "mysql". Verify the `path` environment variable is set properly for your Java process, specify the full path to the command, or specify a working directory using the [`Runtime.exec(String[], String[], File)` overload](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.io.File%29).

Comment: That works. Thank you @lc . Btw I couldn't figured out what was the issue in code? May be point#2. Am I right? Please enlighten the issue in the code. I have included the quote around query in sys.err.out().

Comment: The biggest one is probably point #3 actually. You were sending your query with literal quotes around it, as if you sent your command line `mysql ... "\"SELECT ...\""`